# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol with working library

Tags: gcc, makefile, dynamic-linking

I've a problem with a project that I compile and run under Linux. It's not related to code, but seems rather to linking or something similiar.

The project compiles fine with a makefile. It builds and links with no errors.

But, when I run the program, it does not start and this error appears on the console:

> ./MyProgram: symbol lookup error: /path/to/library/libMyLibrary.so: undefined symbol: system__finalization_root__adjust

The library path is defined with an environment variable. It's found in my pc (otherwise link will fail).

I've tried following things with my pc and another developer pc:

- The exact same project (source, makefile) is compiled in the other pc, and when it starts from that pc it works. I've tried to checkout the project in other pc (we use git) and to copy my own project folder to other pc bypassing git. No problems in both cases.
- I've tried to copy my executable to the other pc, and the executable in that pc has the same error.
- I've tried to copy in my pc the executable compiled with the other pc, and it starts correctly.
- I've replaced in my pc the library with the one copied by the other pc. Nothing changes.
- I've searched the library in my filesystem. Only that copy exists.
- The library path is into LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- I've checked the gcc version, and both my pc and other pc have the same version.

What other can I try in order to fix this?

Comment: So does your library have this symbol or not? What is `nm -d /path/to/library/libMyLibrary.so | grep system__finalization_root__adjust` output? If not, why your program depends on that symbol? Is there any other library that defines it?

Comment: It seems that it has it. I obtain (after changing -d with -D) `U system__finalization_root__adjust`

Comment: `U` is `undefined` (`man nm`), so no good. Should your program define this symbol?

Comment: It's defined in another library, in the same folder of my library, that uses it: `000000000022be40 T system__finalization_root__adjust`. I link both of them into my makefile.

Comment: Check `ldd your_program` and `ldd your_library.so`. Library that contains symbol in question should correctly appear in both outputs.

Comment: It does not appear in my binary and in my library, while it appears in the binary compiled with other pc. But the makefile linking command is the same in both cases and I use `-lmylibrary -lotherlibrary`.

Comment: Show the makefile snippet that compiles the library and binary in question?

Comment: I've solved my problem. the other library was not linked in my executable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088100/gcc-build-links-but-shared-library-does-not-appear-with-ldd