# gcc build links but shared library does not appear with ldd

Tags: gcc, linker, ldd

I've a program that I must build. The program depends on `libA`, and `libA` depends on `libB`. Both libs are in the same folder but `ldd libA.so` does not include `libB.so` so I must add it while linking it.

This is my `gcc` command:

> gcc -L/path/to/libraries/lib -lA -lB -I/path/to/libraries/include main.cpp

The program builds and links, but it does not start. It gives me following error:

> ./a.out: symbol lookup error: /path/to/libraries/lib/libA.so: undefined symbol: symbol_used_in_libA_but_defined_in_libB

With `ldd` I can see that `libB.so` is not included in my binary:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffaecd9000)
libA.so => /path/to/libraries/lib/libA.so (0x00007effc02a4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007effbfebb000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007effbfca5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007effc05cb000)
```

I have these conditions:

- `/path/to/libraries` is inside `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- running `ldconfig` is ok and `ldconfig -p` find both `libA.so` and `libB.so`
- If in gcc command I change `-lB` with `-lBB` it gives me a linker error, so I think that `gcc` find correctly `libB.so` even if it does not link it inside the executable.

What I'm doing wrong? What I can do in order to link the executable to both libraries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most Linux distributions (I assume you are using Linux based on the output of `ldd`) seem to configure `gcc` as to pass `--as-needed` to `ld` by default (e.g., see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking#Only_link_with_needed_libraries) for Debian). This means the final library/executable will only depend on a library (i.e., have a `DT_NEEDED` tag for that library) if some symbol of that library is actually used by the library/executable.

In your case, `main.cpp` does not use any functions of `libB` so the linker does not add `libB` as a dependency of the final executable. You can work around it by passing the `--no-as-needed` flag to the linker. E.g.,

> gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed ...

Of course, the proper fix is to relink `libA` and make sure it lists `libB` as a dependency.

Comment: This solved my problem thanks. I cannot rebuild the library because it's not mine. Anyway I must check because same command with same libraries in my colleague pc works instead..