# GNU autotool shared lib dependencies Build OK but runtime symbol lookup ERROR

Tags: c, linux, linker, autotools, ldd

I have a funny error, please help me!

I have a main.c, liba.so, libb.so.

liba.so has a public function func_a(), and libb.so has public function func_b().

main.c call func_a() and func_a() calls func_b() inside:

main.c:

```
main()
{
    bla_bla();
    func_a();
}
```

liba.c:

```
func_a()
{
    bla_bla...
    func_b(); 
}
```

libb.so is installed in the /usr/local/lib and liba.so is compiled at the same time with main.c.

In my Makefile.am:

```
 main_SOURCES = main.c 

 main_LDADD = liba.la -lb
```

Compiling Okay with the 'main' binary output.
But when start 'main' I got the issue like:

```
 .libs/main: symbol lookup error: .libs/liba.so.0: undefined symbol:
 func_b
```

If I call func_b() inside main.c, the issue is resolved.

Do you have any suggestion for me to overcome this issue?
I am also curious why linker does not mark libb.so as NEEDED even though I have listed in the main_LDADD.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with how `liba.la` is built, and you haven't presented any information about that.  We don't have enough information to do more than speculate,

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I found out the similar issue and it fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088100/gcc-build-links-but-shared-library-does-not-appear-with-ldd?rq=1